# Filtering results in SQL

Tags: sql

Say I have a table as follows:

```
right | group_id | score
1         1          5.6
0         1         3.1
0         1         -1.5
0         1          7        
1         2          4.3
0         2          55.8
0         1         -6
```

How would I sort by group (so all the group 1's are together, 2's etc..) then sort by score. (something like Order by group_id, score). But then I want to filter out everything but the top three results for each group. I.E the resulting table would be:

```
right | group_id | score
0         1          7
1         1         5.6
0         1         3.1
0         1          7        
1         2          55.8
0         2          4.3
```

Thanks!

Comment: (1) Tag your question with the database you are using.  (2) SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  You cannot recover the original ordering unless a column represents the ordering.

Answer (score 2):

Using ANSI SQL, you can do:

```
select right, group_id, score
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by groupid order by score desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 3
order by groupid;
```